# How to display additional fields in MongoDB's group aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I started learning MongoDB and I am trying to find how to display addtional fields in the group query.

Say I have the following document and I want to find the maximum score taken by a student in every class.

```
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 1, "student_id" : 40 }, "avgStudentScore" : 62 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 1, "student_id" : 44 }, "avgStudentScore" : 79 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 2, "student_id" : 0 }, "avgStudentScore" : 53 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 2, "student_id" : 24 }, "avgStudentScore" : 60 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 0, "student_id" : 15 }, "avgStudentScore" : 51 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 0, "student_id" : 25 }, "avgStudentScore" : 66 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 0, "student_id" : 30 }, "avgStudentScore" : 32 }
```

I can do that using the following group aggregation query.

```
{
    $group:
    {
        "_id" : 
        {
            "class_id" : "$_id.class_id",
        },
        "maxStudentScore" :
        {
            $max : "$avgStudentScore"
        }
    }
}
```

My result would be something like,

```
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 1 }, "maxStudentScore" : 79 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 2 }, "maxStudentScore" : 60 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 0 }, "maxStudentScore" : 66 }
```

But I lost the student_id who got the maximum score. How can I display the student_id as well in my final result? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try sort before you group, so you can use the first to pick the student id.

```
aggregate([ {
    $sort: {
        "_id.class_id": 1,
        "avgStudentScore": -1
    }
},{
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            "class_id": "$_id.class_id",
        },
        "student_id": {
            $first: "$_id.student_id"
        },
        "maxStudentScore": {
            $max: "$avgStudentScore"
        }
    }
}])
```

Sample Output:

```
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 2 }, "student_id" : 24, "maxStudentScore" : 60 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 1 }, "student_id" : 44, "maxStudentScore" : 79 }
{ "_id" : { "class_id" : 0 }, "student_id" : 25, "maxStudentScore" : 66 }
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to make use of $first to get the answer. Now I have a better understanding. Thanks.